# Custom post type to lead to single post type instead of shortcode modal

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have inherited a website. In a section there's a few custom post types, and they are placed there with a shortcode. They have a functionality that when you clikc on one, instead of going to the single post type page, which exists and is what I want to achieve (basically the easy functionality). they display a modal. I have found out that this modal is defined in inc/shortcodes.php. I'm not really familiar with this. Is there a way to remake this wp_Query to go back to it's basic, no modal functionality?

```
function mostrar_obras_en_curso($atts, $content = null) {

    //add_filter( 'post_limits', 'somhi_query_limit_8' );
   $new_loop = new WP_Query ( array(
      'post_type'     => 'obras_en_curso',
      'pagination'    => false,
      'posts_per_page' => -1
   )  );

    if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post(); ?>

        <?php
        $id = get_the_id();
        $modalid = 'modal-'.$id;
        ?>

            <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">
                <a href="#" data-reveal-id="<?php echo $modalid ?>">
                    <div class="obras-container">
                        <div class="obras-img">
                            <?php 
                            the_post_thumbnail();
                            $img1 = get_field('img-1');
                            $img2 = get_field('img-2'); 
                            ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="obras-text">
                            <h4><?php the_title() ?></h4>
                            <p><?php the_field('description'); ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div><!-- col -->

            <!-- start of modal -->
            <div id="<?php echo $modalid ?>" class="reveal-modal obras-en-curso" data-reveal style="opacity: 1; visibility: hidden; display: none;">

                <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>

                <div class="container container-slider">
                    <div class="obras-curso-slider">
                        <ul>
                        <?php
                        for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
                            $img = get_field('img-'.$i);
                            if( !empty($img) ): ?>
                                <li><img src="<?php echo $img['url']; ?>"/></li>
                            <?php endif;
                        }
                        ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- project-slider -->
                </div><!-- container -->

            </div><!-- modal -->

    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change this line :

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="<?php echo $modalid ?>">
```

to :

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
```